# Converting a binary file to Base64 in client-side code

Tags: gwt

Is it possible to convert a binary file into Base64 in client side code?

I am doing this because I need to upload to server in a way that it done through GWT RPC.

I mean, like saving a standard Java Object:

```
public class Image implements Serializable {

    private String username;
    private String album;
    private String creationDate; 
    private String base64image;
    // etc.

    public Image () {

    }

        // Code omitted
}
```

Comment: check this link http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html. It is javascript though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that Base64 image has some issues with older browsers regarding file sizes. So I guess doing Base64 image is not a good idea.

Comment: Which browsers specifically?